# Sum of two cells in the same column with a lag of n cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a simple question on Excel for which I cannot easily find an answer on the web.

Let us assume that I want to sum the cell A1 and the cell AN where N is a number in a given cell.

How can I easily use the sum function to achieve this ?

**Example :**
If n=2, I sum A1 and A3.
If n=10, I sum A1 and A11, etc. where the number n is the cell, let's say, B1.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Use `indirect` function

Answer (score 1):

Use this formula

```
=sum(A1, indirect("A"&(B1+1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Didn't it serve your purpose?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the non volatile INDEX:

```
=SUM(A1,INDEX(A:A,B1))
```

Where B1 is the cell in which N is placed.

IF you meant to sum all cells between A1 and AN then we would use:

```
=SUM(A1:INDEX(A:A,B1))
```

Unlike Indirect this formula is not Volatile and will only recalculate when the data changes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ! Do you recommend any book or website to learn all these excel formulas ? (I am beginner in Excel and would like to master it relatively quickly)